# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in PHP while printing into HTML Table

Tags: php, html-parsing

I currently this error while parsing for Stock price from Yahoo. 
I receive only for some stocks however. 
I've looked through some other posts and haven't been able to resolve this.

Here's my scraper code:

```
<?php
//session_start();
#$stockname = "COALINDIA.NS";
$stockname = "AAPL";
#$stockname = "GOOG";
#$stockname = "TCS.NS";

$url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' . $stockname;

$data = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($data);
libxml_clear_errors();
$dom->saveHTML();

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$price = $xpath->query('//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[1]/text()');
$sign = $xpath->query('//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[2]/text()');
$change = $xpath->query('//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[2]/text()[2]');

$current_price = $price->item(0)->nodeValue;
$gain_and_percent = $sign->item(0)->nodeValue . $change->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $current_price;
echo "<br>";
echo "Gain (Gain %):  ". $gain_and_percent;
?>
```

The error I receive is:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Portfolio-Manager/scripts/scraper.php on line 27

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Portfolio-Manager/scripts/scraper.php on line 28

This refers to the lines where I assign the variable $current_price and $gain_and_percent. I do not receive this notice when I echo values separately, however I do when I assign into a HTML Table as follows:

```
<?php
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<td>
<?php
$stockname = $symbol;
require 'scripts/scraper.php';
echo $current_price;
?>
</td>
```

Thank you for looking over my code and your time.

Comment: `$price->item(0)` is likely returning a `null` value, and attempting to get the `nodeValue` attribute of `null` is causing the error to be thrown. Check if this is the case and examine your prior lines of code to determine where the issue is arising.

Comment: At no point in your code do you check that anything has completed successfully, you just carry on processing and end up with an error - which is not surprising at times.

Comment: Hey Nigel, I haven't posted my check code (most of them are now commented out in my original code), I was only unable to find a solution to check for my nodeValue attribute :)

Comment: Looking into it Fleming, thank you :)